# Uniformly integrable random variables remain uniformly integrable after centering

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a familiy of uniformly integrable random variables. I want to show that the family $\{X_i - E[X_i]\}_{i \in I}$ has the same property, i.e.
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists C > 0: \sup_{i \in I} E\big[\mathbf{1}_{\{ |X_i - E(X_i) | > C\}} \, |X_i - E[X_i]| \big] \leq \varepsilon.
$$
How can I show this?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\U}{\mathscr{U}}\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$Let $\U$ be a uniformly integrable family of random variables over a probability space $(\Omega,\mathfrak{M},\P)$. Now define $$\U_c=\{X-\E(X)~:~X\in\U\}$$ to be the set of centered random variables. We claim that $\U$ is bounded in $L^1(\Omega,\P)$. Fix any $\varepsilon>0$ and let $C$ be the corresponding constant as in your definition of uniform integrability. Now for any $X\in\U$, $$\E|X|\leq E(|X|;|X|\leq C)+\E(|X|;|X|>C)\leq C\P(|X|\leq C)+\varepsilon\leq C + \varepsilon.$$
So we see that $\U$ is bounded in $L^1$, and in turn we deduce by Minkowski's inequality that $\U_c$ is bounded in $L^1(\Omega,\P)$. Let $M$ denote the constant which uniformly bounds $\U_c$ in $L^1$.

Let $\varepsilon$ and $C$ be as above. Now fix some $X\in\U$, and we will consider the corresponding random variable $X_c=X-\E(X)\in\U_c.$ By Markov's inequality we see that $\P(|X-\E(X)|>K)\leq M/K$ for any any $K$, and so
\begin{align*}
\E(|\E(X)|;|X-\E(X)|>K)&=\E(X)|\P(|X-\E(X)|>K)\leq \frac{M^2}{K}
\end{align*}
We also have the following estimate
\begin{align*}
\E(|X|;|X-\E(X)|>K)&\leq \E(|X|;|X-\E(X)|>K,|X|\leq C) + \E(|X|;|X-\E(X)|>K,|X|>C) \\
& \leq C\P(|X-\E(X)|>K)+\varepsilon\\
& \leq \frac{MC}{K}+\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Now by taking a sufficiently large $K$ we can bound both of the above estimates uniformly by $2\varepsilon$. Now by Minkowski's inequality again we have 
\begin{align*}
\E(|X-\E(X)|;|X-\E(X)|>K)&\leq\E(|X|;|X-\E(X)|\geq K)+\E(|\E(X)|;|X-\E(X)|>K) \\
&\leq 4\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary and since $K=K(M,C,\varepsilon)$, we see that $\U_c$ is a uniformly integrable family.

**Note:** There is an equivalent characterization/definition of uniform integrability from which this result follows more or less immediately from. *A family of random variables $\U$ is unifomly integrable if and only if $\U$ is bounded in $L^1$ and for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists some $\delta >0$ such that for all measurable $F$ with $\P(F)<\delta$ and $X\in\U$, then $\E(|X|;F)<\varepsilon$.*